# How to get FBSDKAccessToken from FBSDKAuthenticationToken

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-access-token, event-tracking

In case of LAT FB login, we are just getting FBSDKAuthenticationToken and FBSDKAccessToken is nil.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/limited-login/ios/

FBSDK Login is now using the Advertiser tracking flag(user consent)for iOS 14.
How to get FBSDKAccessToken from FBSDKAuthenticationToken? Or how to get FB profile from FBSDKAuthenticationToken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2021/01/19/facebook-login-updates-new-limited-data-mode/) of Facebook, limited mode and classic mode use different authentication methods behind.

Limited Login mode is based on the OpenID Connect standard.
Classic Login mode utilizes oAuth 2.0.

Therefore, I think there's no way to get access token by authentication token.
But we can get basic profile of user under limited login mode. There's a code snippet from [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/limited-login/ios) reveals how to do that.

```
let loginManager = LoginManager()

// Ensure the configuration object is valid
guard let configuration = LoginConfiguration(tracking: .limited, nonce: "123") 
else {
    return
}

loginManager.logIn(configuration: configuration) { result in
    switch result {
    case .cancelled, .failed:
        // Handle error
        break
    case .success:
        // getting user ID
        let userID = Profile.current?.userID

        // getting pre-populated email
        let email = Profile.current?.email

        // getting id token string
        let tokenString = AuthenticationToken.current?.tokenString
    }
}
```

Also note that limited login mode does not support Graph API.